# Render between outdoor and indoor

Tags: light

I've some experience with Blender (and previously 3DS Max), but I only do something with this once every year.

I have a scene where I want to render somethings outside and other inside, but I am having trouble with the amount of light that I have inside of the building. I know that our eyes can adjust to the light around, and I was hoping that I had a property for the camera to do that instead of tweek HDR sky.

Is the Exposure settings on `Scene` property or there exists a better way ?

Real World

[image]

Outside - Exposure (0)

[image: Outside]

Inside - Exposure (0)

[image: Inside 2]

Inside - Exposure (3.0)

[image: Inside]

For my lightning settings (Render) I have:

Clamp direct (2.0)
Clamp indirect (0.0)
Light Sampling Thr (1.0)

I've notice that the noise reduces if I rise Clamp indirect., but also I lose a little bit of direct light. (Exposure: 3.0)

[image: Inside 3]

What should be the next step to have better inside light and less noise on render ?

Thanks.

EDIT: End up using Portal Light and increase the `samples` in the scene property. It doesn't have so much noise. But I need to bump both HDR `strength` and Exposure to 4.

[image]

Comment: You can adjust scene exposure, but it is probably easier to just set up two separate scenes with linked objects, and create an adequate lighting system for each

Comment: you could try using light portals.

Comment: @VirgilSisoe, thanks. That might be one possible solution. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1LjLyTBbl6s